# Cannot figure out this migradoc error

Tags: c#-4.0, migradoc

i m having the stack trace. there is no line number. wen i work on my system its working correctly. Please help if anyone can get a clue

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: text
   at MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.ParagraphElements.AddText(String text)
   at MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.DocumentElements.AddParagraph(String text)
   at MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Tables.Cell.AddParagraph(String paragraphText)
   at Emily.Snippets.PrintClass.PrintChallanReport()
   at Emily.Snippets.PrintClass..ctor(String mode, Int32 challanNumber)
   at Emily.Controls.Reports.ChallanReportCtrl.llblPrint_LinkClicked(Object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel.OnLinkClicked(LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AddText is being called with a null parameter for text.

So it seems your method PrintClass.PrintChallanReport() calls Cell.AddParagraph passing null as parameter.

Comment: thanx ThomasH for ur reply.. i'll check with your solution.